# How to remove a scene after the another one has loaded

Tags: unity, c#

[image: SCENE 0[![SCENE 1]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph8Fv.jpg)[[image: IGNORE THE TOP SCREEN]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8atA.jpg)I'm having this problem in Unity where I load a new scene, but the original is still overlapping it. How would you remove the original scene?

Comment: Hi and welcome to GameDev community! I'm not sure about what you mean by "overlapping", could you expand on that please? Adding a gif or an image to show us what is happening, is also a useful hint to help us come up with a solution that will satisfy your needs ;)

Comment: There you go @Gabriele Vierti. Ignore the top screen

Comment: what do your first and second scenes look like? I'm not able to get that from the image you attached.

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: What code are you using to load your scene?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in `Unity.SceneManagment`, called `SceneManager.LoadSceneASync()`, which is used to determine wheather the loading operation is complete.

One way to use it would be call a Coroutine, and make it run until the scene is fully loaded. Once the loading operation is done Unity will then switch to the fully loaded scene.

When you want to load the scene, you do

```
StartCoroutine(LoadYourAsyncScene());
```

Then you create the coroutine:

```
IEnumerator LoadYourAsyncScene()
{
    AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("YourSceneName"); // change "YourSceneName" with the scene you want to load

    // wait until the scene fully loads
    while (!asyncLoad.isDone)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this go in the update loop?

Comment: Yes. You could start the coroutine after the user pressed a key or a button for instance.

Comment: I am getting the following error message for line 12,32:

Comment: Error CS1525: Unexpected symbol '(', expecting ';', '=' or ','

Comment: @user9851927 that error gets thrown when there is an invalid expression somewhere in your code.